# Como capturar múltiplos valores do HTML com forms do django

Tags: python, django

Para que o `html` envie um campo do tipo `select` com vários valores selecionados é necessário colocar a notação `[]` no atributo name do `html`:

```
<select name="categories[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-input__select">
    {% for cat in categories %}
        <option value="{{ cat.id }}">{{ cat.id }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

como faço para capturar esse valor usando o `Form.forms` do django?

Tentei usar o:

```
categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False)
```

porém ao usar o `form.cleaned_data` o valor de `categories[]` fica vazio.

debug antes do `cleaned_data`:

```
'categories[]': ['AB', 'AU'], 'brands_are_inclusive': ['true']
```

debug após o `cleaned_data`:

```
'categories': [], 'brands_are_inclusive': 'true'
```

Comment: Cara, até onde eu sei essa gambiarra de usar `[]` para denotar múltiplos valores é coisa do PHP. Em outros servidores basta apenas usar `name="categories"` pois ao enviar para o servidor vira algo como: `categories=1&categories=3&categories=5`.

Comment: se eu não colocar o `[]` a validação de `MultipliChoiceField` não captura o campo ou seja, não é uma lista

Answer (score -1):

No Django **não é preciso** usar `[]` após o nome do campo, você pode remover isso do seu HTML.

O problema é que o `MultipleChoicesField` **requer** um parâmetro `choices` que tem que ser informado para que o django consiga reconhecer as opções. Veja [na documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield):

> Takes one **extra required argument**, `choices`, as for `ChoiceField`.

Um exemplo que funcionaria:

```
 categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
     choices=[('AB', 'Albânia'), ('AU', 'Austrália')])
```

Comment: no meu caso os `choices` não são pré-definidos, o usuario ira envia-los através de um form que utiliza um plugin JS.

Comment: @RFL Então você precisa dar um jeito de alguma forma resgatar esses valores do usuário, talvez por ajax, ou enviá-los no request de alguma forma, antes de criar o `MultipleChoicesField`, pois, se quiser usar essa classe, é obrigatório informar as opções, como você pode ver na documentação que eu linkei. A classe não funciona sem passar esse parâmetro.